# Showing that $D^b(k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n])$ is Calabi–Yau

Tags: abstract-algebra, homological-algebra, derived-categories

$\def\Hom{\operatorname{Hom}}$I am trying to work myself through the proof Lemma 4.1. in [this paper](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Ebernhard.keller/publ/KellerCYtriangCat.pdf) in a simplified setup. Let $A$ be the commutative algebra $A = k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ over some field $k$. If $M$ is a chain complex of $A$-modules, let $DM = \Hom_k(M, k)$.

Every $\Hom$ denotes the derived Hom-complex in the derived category, and $\otimes$ denotes the derived tensor product complex.

With $V = k^n$, let $K$ be the Koszul complex $K = 0 \to A \otimes_k\bigvee^n V \to \dotsb \to A \otimes_k \bigvee^0 V$. Note that $V \simeq k$ in the derived category $D^b(A)$. Let $\Omega = \Hom_A(k, A) \simeq \Hom_A(K, A)$. One checks that in this particular $\Omega \simeq k[n]$ both in $D^b(A)$ and $D^b(k)$, where $[n]$ denotes the downward shift of complexes (i.e., $X[n]_q = X_{n+q}$).

I want to show that $\Hom_A(M, N[-n]) \simeq D \Hom_A(N, M)$ for all complexes $M, N \in D^b(A)$. So far, I have tried:

\begin{align}
D\Hom_A(M, N[-n]) 
&= D\Hom_A(M[n], M) \\
&\simeq D\Hom_A(M \otimes_k \Omega, N)\\
&\simeq D\Hom_k(M, \Hom_A(\Omega, N))\\
&\simeq D(DM \otimes_k \Hom_A(\Omega, N))\\
&\simeq \Hom_k(\Hom_A(\Omega, N), M)\\
&\simeq \Hom_k(\underbrace{\Hom_A(\Omega,A)}_{K} \otimes_A N, M)\\
&\simeq \Hom_A(N, \Hom_k(K, M))\\
&\simeq \Hom_A(N, M)
\end{align}

using that $K \simeq k$, and that $\Omega$ is a chain complex of finite rank free modules. I'm not sure if the isomorphism $\Hom_A(\Omega, N) \simeq \Hom_A(\Omega, A) \otimes_A N$ really works with the derived Hom, and if $\Omega$ is not projective but a complex of projectives.

So: is this proof correct?